# Angular: Kick off Multiple methods and zip result at the end

Tags: angular, typescript, jszip

I have a single method for which zip and save works on response of JSON array and splitting them to individual file..

```
zip: JSZip = new JSZip();
folder: JSZip = new JSZip();

this.apicall.api1()
.subscribe(
  response => {
  for (let r of response) {
    this.folder = this.zip.folder("result/api1");
    this.folder.file(`${r.actorname}.json`, JSON.stringify(r));
    
  }

  
 this.zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "result.zip");
});

});
```

But I have multiple api calls (all may / may not be called always due to selection on execution)

`this.apicall.api2(), this.apicall.api3(), this.apicall.api4()` and so on

I want to put each result in a separate folder like above `"result/api2"` `"result/api3"` etc.. and then once all are done we put it in the result.zip

How do we move the generateAsync out of the api1() and then feed results from others method to it in the end with different folder structures and generate final zip?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

It takes an array of promises and in turn returns a Promise that will resolve when all the async code (API calls) have successfully completed. You can then make the final callback of zipping on all returned responses after that.

Something like the following:

```
zip: JSZip = new JSZip();

async zipProcess(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const callsAndNames = [
      { name: 'api1', call: this.apicall.api1 },
      { name: 'api2', call: this.apicall.api2 },
      { name: 'api3', call: this.apicall.api3 },
      { name: 'api4', call: this.apicall.api4 }
      // ...
    ];
    const responsesAndNames = await Promise.all(
      callsAndNames.map(async ({ name, call }) => ({
        name,
        response: await firstValueFrom(call())
      }))
    );
    responsesAndNames.forEach(({ name, response }) => {
      const folder = this.zip.folder(`result/${name}`);
      for (let r of response) {
        folder.file(`${r.actorname}.json`, JSON.stringify(r));
      }
    });
    this.zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) {
      saveAs(content, 'result.zip');
    });
  } catch (error) {
    /* handle error */
    console.error(error);
  }
}

await this.zipProcess();
```

The code may not be exactly what you want but I feel it should give you an overview of how to use `Promise.all`

Given that each API call has a name, I started out with their names so that the names are still available when adding the responses in the zip folders.

I'm a fan of one-liners, they make the code shorter. So I used them greatly, hope it's not an issue for you. Especially as I combined them with [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the function parameters.

I also wrapped the whole thing in try and catch because we should always handle possible errors.

I tweaked the folder logic based on how I felt the stuff works, if I'm wrong, improve it in your implementation.

[`firstValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom) is a function from the rxjs package that converts Observables to Promises. [The `.toPromise()` method on Observables have been deprecated in favor of this `firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise). I used `firstValueFrom` because I noticed `.subscribe` in the code, insinuating that the `.apiN` methods return Observables and not Promises. So we need to convert the Observables to Promises to use the `Promise.all` syntax.

If that was wrong, or if you want this process to be continuously repeating, that is as Observables continuously emitting values from those calls, and not as Promises that will resolve once and stop; Then maybe you shouldn't use `Promise.all`, but rather use rxjs operators like [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) or [`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) to obtain API result values before proceeding to the folder zipping logic.

But then this is an API call so chances are you want it to run only once and hence `Promise.all` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks.. our rxjs package is old (6.x) so can't find firstValueFrom to use. What can we change in your code to make it work? If you could give that part would be great so we can try it..

Comment: Okay. Change `firstValueFrom(call())` to `call().toPromise()`. That should work. I mentioned about this in the answer too.

Comment: yeah I had tried it but I think I am getting another error due to this.apicall.api1 authentication .. Normally I call it as this.apicall.api1().subscribe() and it works but for this case calling it as this.apicall.api1 and gives an error.. calling with subscribe says subscription has no signature

Comment: Okay what exactly is the error when you use this method. So we know how to solve it. Also, you can use combineLatest and merge on the observables directly if you feel that promise is the problem

Comment: So while using `call().toPromise()` and using `this.apicall.api1` we get error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authService')`... when using `this.apicall.api1().subscribe()` we get `Type 'Subscription' has no call signatures.`

Comment: So this time the problem is not with this part of the code but with the AuthService from where the calls are made.  Post it too and post more code that will help us understand the codebase. I gave you the above solutions based on the original snippets you posted

Comment: upgraded to latest rxjs (Can roll back too) just to test.. the code has same error as above.. it basically goes and fails on doing auth where this is

`public user: Observable<User>;
//which is getting defined below
this.userSub= new BehaviorSubject(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
this.user = this.userSub.asObservable();`

Comment: Hi @ChrisT, the problem is not the above code you shared. Check the question you posted. I addressed just that section where you said you wanted to complete API calls. The errors you are getting are unrelated to the code you sent. There is clearly no user or sessionStorage or authService in the the code you shared. LIke I said previously, to solve these second problems you are having, you have to share ALL the code related to those to help us solve it.

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried to explain it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73003920/angular-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-on-promise